# Delphi Indy SMTPServer read multi-part message

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo and Indy 10.6.2.5366.

I'm trying to receive some SMTP messages from a foreign system, and the messages received are using multi-part MIME.  I need to extract some fields and values from the message.

When I read the body as in the Indy SMTPServer Demo, the body is empty, but the body is written to the saved file.

How do I read that body into a `TStringList`? Is this a manual thing I must develop, or is there some method (couldn't find one) to do this?

This is what I do (Inspired from the demo):

```
procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1MsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  AMsg: TStream; var LAction: TIdDataReply);
var
 LMsg : TIdMessage;
 LMsg2 : TIdMessage;
 LStream : TFileStream;
 i : integer;
 AMsgpart : TidMessagePart;

begin
// When a message is received by the server, this event fires.
// The message data is made available in the AMsg : TStream.
// In this example, we will save it to a temporary file, and the load it using
// IdMessage and parse some header elements.

  AddToLog('Msg recv '+formatdatetime('hh:nn:ss', Now));

  LMsg2 := TIdMessage.Create;
  try
    LMsg2.LoadFromStream(AMsg);
    ToLabel.Caption := LMsg2.Recipients.EMailAddresses;
    FromLabel.Caption := LMsg2.From.Text;
    SubjectLabel.Caption := LMsg2.Subject;

// not working
//    Memo1.Lines := LMsg2.Body;

// so what to do with this multi-part message in MIME format.
    for i := 0 to LMsg2.MessageParts.Count-1 do
    begin
      if (LMsg2.MessageParts.Items[i].PartType = mptText) then
       begin
         //AddToLog(LMsg2.MessageParts.Items[i].);
         AMsgpart := LMsg2.MessageParts.Items[i];




       end
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(LMsg2);
  end;

  // Just write to a file as in demo
  LStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.exename) + format('test(%d).eml',[mailno]), fmCreate);
  Try
    LStream.CopyFrom(AMsg, 0);
  Finally
    FreeAndNil(LStream);
  End;

end;
```

The message stream when written to a file looks like this

```
Received: from WIN-2SP97MPF39L[192.168.10.141] (helo=DesigoCC1) by HPNB2.hnit.local[192.168.10.131] with esmtp (My SMTP Server)
From: Alarms@DCC.dk
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 09:46:39 +0100
To: mail@mail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?QWxhcm0=?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
       boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0006_01CAB9FA.E6640E80"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0006_01CAB9FA.E6640E80
Content-Type: text/plain;
    format=flowed;
    charset="utf-8";
    reply-type=original
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Date:2/2/2018 9:45:03 AM:02/02 09:45
Category:Information:
Desc:Servers.Main Server:
DescCompl:Project.Management System.Servers.Main Server
Tag:Mail.SMTP Status
TagCompl:Mail.SMTP Status [Mail]
Status:Quiet
EventComplProject.Management System.Servers.Main Server
Message:N/A
Cause:Mail Error (Wrong SMTP Server):Mail Error 
-----
Message ID: -(6138661-
------=_NextPart_000_0006_01CAB9FA.E6640E80--
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TStream` provided by the `OnMsgReceive` event is the *raw* email data as sent by the remote client.  However, it is NOT in a format that `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()` expects by default.  Specifically, the `TIdMessage.LoadFrom...()` methods expect the data to be in an escaped format that SMTP uses during transmission.  That escaping is undone before the `OnMsgReceive` event is fired.  So, loading the `TStream` as-is *may* cause parsing issues.

Fortunately, Indy has a `IdMessageHelper` unit to address this very issue (see [New TIdMessage helper](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/ChangeLog/20150730.aspx), which describes the issue in more detail).  It introduces new `LoadFrom...()` methods that add an `AUsesDotTransparency` parameter that you can set to False so `TIdMessage` won't expect the escaping anymore while parsing.

As for the content of the email, multi-part MIME bodies are not stored in the `TIdMessage.Body` property, they are stored in `TIdMessagePart`-derived objects, like `TIdText`, in the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` property instead.  So, you need to scan through that property looking for the text you are interested in.

You also have to keep in mind that most of Indy's TCP-based servers are multi-threaded.  The `OnMsgReceive` event is fired in a worker thread, so if you want to access the UI, you must synchronize with the main UI thread.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
uses
  ..., IdGlobalProtocols, IdMessageParts, IdText, IdMessage, IdMessageHelper;

procedure TForm1.IdSMTPServer1MsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  AMsg: TStream; var LAction: TIdDataReply);
var
 LMsg : TIdMessage;
 LStream : TFileStream;
 i : integer;
 LMsgPart : TIdMessagePart;
 LText : TIdText;
begin
  // When a message is received by the server, this event fires.
  // The message data is made available in the AMsg : TStream.

  AddToLog('Msg recv ' + FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', Now));

  LMsg := TIdMessage.Create;
  try
    //LMsg.LoadFromStream(AMsg);
    LMsg.LoadFromStream(AMsg, False);

    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        ToLabel.Caption := LMsg.Recipients.EMailAddresses;
        // FYI, the *true* recipients of the email are stored in the
        // ASender.RCPTList property, which may include additional
        // recipients not specified by TIdMessage.Recipients due to BCCs...

        FromLabel.Caption := LMsg.From.Text;
        // FYI, ASender also has a From property, which is the *true* sender
        // of the email, which may be different than what TIdMessage.From
        // says...

        SubjectLabel.Caption := LMsg.Subject;
      end
    );

    if IsHeaderMediaType(LMsg.ContentType, 'multipart') then
    begin
      LText := nil;
      for i := 0 to LMsg.MessageParts.Count-1 do
      begin
        LMsgPart := LMsg.MessageParts[i];
        if (LMsgPart is TIdText) and
           IsHeaderMediaType(LMsgPart.ContentType, 'text/plain') then
        begin
          //AddToLog(LMsgPart);
          LText := TIdText(LMsgPart);
          Break;
        end
      end;
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          if LText <> nil then
            Memo1.Lines := LText.Body
          else
            Memo1.Clear;
        end
      );
    end
    else if IsHeaderMediaType(LMsg.ContentType, 'text') then
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Memo1.Lines := LMsg.Body;
        end
      );
    end else
    begin
      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          Memo1.Clear;
        end
      );
    end;
  finally
    LMsg.Free;
  end;

  // Just write to a file as in demo
  LStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + Format('test(%d).eml', [mailno]), fmCreate);
  try
    LStream.CopyFrom(AMsg, 0);
  finally
    LStream.Free;
  end;

  // Alternatively, AMsg is a TMemoryStream by default, unless you
  // provide your own TStream in the OnBeforeMsg event...
  //
  // TMemoryStream(AMsg).SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + Format('test(%d).eml', [mailno]));
end;
```